# How to send notification from android to spacific users

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How to send data from android to specific user of my app

My scenario is that
There are three users in my app

1- Fazal
2- Ali
3- Haider

how to send notification from Fazal to Haider in android

I can't find any tutorial on google and Youtube

Comment: You can create a topic in Google GCM and make the users Fazal and Haider communicate using GCM XMPP implemented in app server. Please see the link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Cloud Messaging on your app each user has an unique token Id. If you have a server you need to store all tokens on it after the GCM token registration has been done otherwise if you haven't a server all of your clients need to share own tokens each others and in this way you can make a http call to GCM to sent a notification to other clients.